# Windows software updates and Java applications

Tags: java, windows, jvm

How likely is that the functioning of a medium-sized Java application using JDK7 is affected by a Windows update? This seems to be a common explanation for unexplainable behavior of software at my work and I'd like to know how likely if at all possible this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO: While it is highly unlikely, if your Java program uses native libraries it could be a regular problem.  For a Pure Java application, it should make things better not worse.

If Windows Updates regularly cause problems, they should stop performing a windows update of a working machine to one which does not work.